# photoshop scripting - getting document bit depth

Tags: photoshop

How would I get bit depth (8/16/32) of current document? 
I'm using JavaScript. I looked through reference manual, but I could not find any property or function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bitsPerChannel

```
alert(activeDocument.bitsPerChannel)

returns "BitsPerChannelType.EIGHT"
```

You might want to use this function to change the bit depth

```
convertBitDepth(8)

function convertBitDepth(bitdepth)
{
   var id1 = charIDToTypeID( "CnvM" );
   var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
   var id2 = charIDToTypeID( "Dpth" );
   desc1.putInteger( id2, bitdepth );
   executeAction( id1, desc1, DialogModes.NO );
}
```